# If 2 rooks are on the same Rank how to record the move if one rook moves towards the other?

Tags: notation

Like for example a rook is on f1 and another is on a1 and I move the rook on f1 to b1 what would I write?

```
[Title "Notation to move the f-Rook to b1?"]
[FEN "4k3/8/8/8/8/8/8/R4R1K w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Moving to the left means different things for black and white. You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 6):

With rooks on **a1** & **f1**, you would write: **Rfb1**.

With knights on **a1** & **a5**, you would write **N5b3**.

With knights on **a1**, **a5** & **c5** :), you would write **Na5b3**.

It's all described here very well:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)

Answer (score 1):

To move the f-Rook to b1: `Rfb1`, where R is Rook, f is the starting file (or ranks in some cases) and b1 is the final square. 'f' is written to denote which Rook moved since both Rooks are on the same rank.